# Reason of ORA-00604 - ORA-00904: on online Redefining

Tags: oracle

I made [Redefining Tables Online](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables007.htm#ADMIN11674) on a table . It worked fine but later when I tried to truncate the table I got this error .

```
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-00904: "CURRENT_SCN": invalid identifier.
```

also I get the same error when I move the table:

```
 alter table tab1 move;
```

what is the reason of the error ? If you need more information please ask me.

Comment: Is there a materialized view log on the table? Can you remove it?

Comment: @BalazsPapp I run this SELECT *
FROM  all_mviews; and I didnt find on the table tab1 ...

Comment: Query `ALL_MVIEW_LOGS`, not `ALL_MVIEWS`.

Comment: I found it like that `MLOG$_TAB1` .. how to drop it ?  this didnt worked Drop materialized view MLOG$_TAB1 @BalazsPapp

Comment: `DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON TAB1;`

Comment: @BalazsPapp it worked , but did this log appeared ? is it from online redefenition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performing online redefinition creates materialized view log on the source table, that is where DML changes are tracked during the redefinition process.

Finishing the online redefinition gracefully (finish_redef_table or abort_redef_table) removes the materialized view log automatically, otherwise it will stay there.

Truncating the table with an existing materialized view works with the following syntax:

`truncate table tab1 purge materialized view log;`

Or just simply drop the materialized view log before.

Without specifying the above, truncate fails because of a recursive query on SYS.MLOG$, as that table does not have the column `CURRENT_SCN` (version <= 11.2). It is fixed from 12.1.